# An inequality connecting integrals $I_1 = \int\frac{(f-g)^2}{f+g} $ and $I_2 =\int ( \sqrt{f}-\sqrt{g})^2$

Tags: integration, analysis, inequality

Let functions $f,g:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $\int f = \int g =1$. Define the integrals

\begin{equation}
I_1 = \int\frac{(f-g)^2}{f+g} .
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
I_2 =\int ( \sqrt{f}-\sqrt{g})^2.
\end{equation}
It can be seen that $I_2 \leq I_1.$ However, I am trying to find an inequality connecting those two quantities of the form

\begin{equation}
h(I_1) \leq I_2 \leq I_1
\end{equation}
where $h$ some function to be determined in conclusion after bounding. I tried taking the square root of $I_1$

\begin{equation}
\sqrt{I_1} = \sqrt{\int\frac{(f-g)^2}{f+g}} 
\end{equation}
but I can't see how this can be upper bounded by a constant times $I_2$. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$I_1 
= \int\frac{(f-g)^2}{f+g}
= \int\frac{(f+g)^2-4fg}{f+g}
= \int(f+g)-4\int\frac{fg}{f+g}
$.

$I_2 
=\int ( \sqrt{f}-\sqrt{g})^2
=\int ( f+g-2\sqrt{fg})
=\int ( f+g)-2\int\sqrt{fg}
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
I_1-I_2
&=\int(\frac{-4fg}{f+g}+2\sqrt{fg})\\
&=\int\frac{-4fg+2(f+g)\sqrt{fg}}{f+g}\\
&=2\int\frac{-2fg+(f+g)\sqrt{fg}}{f+g}\\
&=2\int\sqrt{fg}\frac{-2\sqrt{fg}+(f+g)}{f+g}\\
&=2\int\sqrt{fg}\frac{(\sqrt{f}-\sqrt{g})^2}{f+g}\\
&=2\int\frac{\sqrt{fg}}{f+g}(\sqrt{f}-\sqrt{g})^2\\
&\ge 0
\qquad\text{if } f\ge 0, g\ge 0, \text{ and }
f+g \ne 0\\
\end{array}
$

Also

$\begin{array}\\
I_1-I_2
&=2\int\frac{\sqrt{fg}}{f+g}(\sqrt{f}-\sqrt{g})^2\\
&\le 2\int\frac{(f+g)/2}{f+g}(\sqrt{f}-\sqrt{g})^2
\qquad\text{since }\sqrt{ab} \le (a+b)/2\\
&=\int(\sqrt{f}-\sqrt{g})^2\\
&=I_2\\
\text{so}\\
I_1
&\le 2I_2\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Yes, I came up with this inequality. I am trying to find another inequality of the opposite direction.

Comment: Aha. I'll play around and see what happens.

Comment: OK. I got $I_2 \le 2I_2$. How's that?